# Find Moment-Generating Function of the Continuous Random Variable X.

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Find Moment Generating Function of Random Variable X in which the Probability Distribution Function is: 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1,  & \text{for 0<x<1} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

I understood the Moment-Generating Function to be $$M_X(t) = E[e^{(tx)}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx}f(x)dx = \int_{x=0}^{x=1} e^{tx}*1dx$$

Solving for this integral (and double-checking via Wolfram Alpha) I was able to determine that
$$\int_{x=0}^{x=1} e^{tx}*1dx \\= \frac{1}{t} e^{tx}|^1_0 \\ \quad= \frac{e^t}{t} - \frac{1}{te^0} \\= \frac{e^t-1}{t}$$

Unfortunately, the solution in the back of the book is as follows... $\text {(John E. Freund's Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 8th Edition)}$ 
$$M_X(t) = \frac{2e^t}{3-e^t}$$

I have no idea where this answer is coming from or where I am going wrong in terms of the Moment Generating Function equation and could definitely use some help! Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is correct (though note that $M_X(0)=1$). Perhaps the solution is for a different problem.

Comment: So this is going to sound stupid... but our professor did say that this Text was known to have errors in the solution guide. However, he didn't inform us that this section specifically was wrong.
So you are saying that with what is given, this is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes. Note that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, and take $a=0,b=1$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate the help and the source! If you don't mind, throw this up as an answer and I'll resolve the question for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the work in the question is correct, except for the minor detail that the case $t=0$ should be handled separately. Since $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1=M_X(0)$, this is a removable singularity.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!